# Is it possible to enable a post build option on a stream - RTC source control?

Tags: clearcase, rtc

I've setup the following to prevent developers from delivering to a stream if the changes being delivered break the build :

I've added a stream which uses the 'Post-Build Deliver' to deliver changes to a separate stream. On the build definition I need to specifiy a workspace to build from, 
but I need to build from the stream. Building from a workspace just builds the changes that are local to a single developer, wheras building 
from a stream will contain multiple changes. Is it possible to enable the post build option on a build definition and also build from a stream instead of building from a workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding RTC "post-build deliver" described in "[How to keep your streams flowing smoothly in Rational Team Concert 3.0.1](https://jazz.net/library/article/649#Example_postBuildDeliver)", that step is about what to do once the workspace has been built.

But, contrary to ClearCase (where a "workspace" or UCM snapshot view would always be associated to an UCM Stream), a Build Definition (with or without "post-build deliver") is always associated to a workspace.
As described in "[Creating Build Forge build definitions](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.build.doc/topics/t_buildforgebuilddef.html)":

> The build definition must refer to a dedicated build workspace, rather than the team stream, so that builds are isolated from ongoing changes in the stream.

When you create said build repository workspace, you will associate a Stream:

> In the New Repository Workspace wizard, on the Select a stream page, select `Flow with a stream` and in the lower pane, **select the repository stream that you want to build from**.
>   **This selection enables the repository workspace to accept changes from the stream**.

So you always build from a (build) workspace. Even when you don't activate a "Post-Build Deliver" option.
The definition of the build workspace determines the Stream from which you are accepting changes.
Said changes will be accepted (from the Stream to the build workspace) each time you are launching a build.
By "change sets", I mean any change set delivered by any developer on that "flow Stream" mentioned in the definition of the build workspace.

Comment: I've updated my question, should be 'Post-Build Deliver' instead of 'Post build action' . I'm using tutorial at : https://jazz.net/library/article/649 . " to make sure that your workspace is the root directory of a UCM snapshot view." How will the change sets from other developers be delivered to this workspace ?

Comment: @user470184 RTC! right. I have edited my answer to address that specific tool.

Comment: "Said changes will be accepted (from the Stream to the build workspace) each time you are launching a build." The changes need to be accepted by the owner of the workspace, they are not automatically added from the builds flow target each time a build is launched ?

Comment: @user470184 there should be automatically accepted, that is the idea behing a build definition and its associated repo workspace: to be a recipient for new changes and build from those evolutions.